# Pyton switcher/dictionary to decode topic and payload from MQTT - Old coder new to python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I'm trying to use Python to listen for MQTT messages and activate some of four relays based on the topic and payload received.

I've seen switcher/dictionary syntax to emulate a switch/case type of function but can't quite get it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The topics/payloads would be:

- Topic = Z1, Z2, Z3 or Z4
- Payload for each would be either = ON or OFF

So if I get a Z1:ON the then I would want to OR in the 1st bit.
Z2:ON I would want to OR in the second bit.  And so forth.

If I get a Z1:OFF then I would want to NOT-AND clear the 1st bit.

I can do the and'ing and or'ing but getting the two switch to work in an optimal (non-embarrassing) way is what I am not getting.

Comment: I've got the MQTT receiving down and it is printing out the message (topic and payload) the next part is jamming the proper bits into the relay control register.

Comment: We can't answer this without seeing the code you've tried and a detailed explanation of how it's not working.

Comment: Nevermind, I'll just do nested if/else blocks. It isn't that many to worry about.